# Is there a way to program an Android or iOS app with php?

Tags: php, android, ios

I have been a php developer for a long time and very comfortable making web applications with it. I want to try to make an app for android and I phones. But it's just for fun, and I am not sure I have enough time to learn a new language right now. I could create this app in php in a short day if it were possible and would prefer not to go through the traditional learning curve of trying to figuring out sonething new. Is there a way to create an app that would just run something similar to an iframe that would then just pull all the functionality from a website?

Comment: check this most relevant to you - https://qr.ae/pGqI8p

Comment: I'm not an expert but I believe you can make an app which is essentially just a HTML front-end, and it could then make HTTP requests (via JS or postback or links) to a PHP backend to run functionality, just like a standard website. But obviously you'd need a server to run the PHP from, and the app would be useless if the device was offline.

Comment: You can use react native or flutter for such reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create a web viewer application. First create a website, host it and just implement that site URL into your android or IOS app. it's just a few lines of code so you don't have to learn from scratch to make the whole app.

follow this link...
https://youtu.be/A8sSRQ5mVqY

Comment: Do you know if there is a way for this to work on ios too?

Comment: yes web view is the only option for both android and for ios.
link to follow for ios app........
https://youtu.be/JafGypqFvs4

Answer (score 2):

you can use **react native** instead of implement native android or iOS.